What do those exclamation marks mean in the documentation for SolveAlways?
Documentation for SolveAlways includes this phrase:

SolveAlways[eqns,vars] is equivalent to Solve[!Eliminate[!eqns,vars]].

I don't understand this. ! is logical negation, right? What is !eqns, and what is !Eliminate?

eqns is typically an And expression (even if presented as a list), which, therefore, can be logically negated. The result of Eliminate is similarly a logical expression which can be negated. So, yes, you've described that sentence in the documentation correctly. Maybe you should just try a few examples to help you understand it.

I see, so ! distributes over lists. So the output of Eliminate is also always a logical expression or a list of logical expressions?

In Mathematica highlight the unknown symbol (e.g., !) and press F1 for help. Alternatively, in this case just look at FullForm[!eqns]

@BobHanlon I knew what ! is, it just never occurred to me it can be applied not only to booleans but also to lists of booleans or to functions that return lists of booleans. Besides, I still don't understand mathematically why not-eliminate-not results in SolveAlways. I decided against a followup question since it is about mathematics rather than Mathematica

I think Daniel's answer, which is taken from the docs without attribution, shows this is easily found in the documentation.

"!" means "Not". E.g. consider:
eqns = (a + b - c) x y - (a - d) == 1 && (c - d + 2) y == (a^2 - b) x;
! eqns // Simplify

a^2 x + (-2 - c + d) y != b x || d + (a + b - c) x y != 1 + a

these are the negation of the first and second equation. Because eqns contains "And" !eqns contains "Or"
Now consider what Eliminate does:
Eliminate[! eqns, {x, y}]

-a^2 + b != 0 || a + b - c != 0 || 2 + c - d != 0 || -1 - a + d != 0

And:
! Eliminate[! eqns, {x, y}] // Simplify

a^2 == b && a + b == c && 2 + c == d && 1 + a == d

Again the exchange of "And" <=> "Or"

When I first read the SolveAlways documentation, I understood the technical details of each step, but the reasoning behind them wasn't immediately clear. In particular, I found myself questioning why double negation is necessary. This question is closely related to how the Eliminate command operates.
Quite generally, one may consider the following logical statement (predicate):
$$F(\mathbf{a},x),$$
where $F$ is a function of parameters $\mathbf{a}$ and a variable $x$ to be eliminated. For illustration, consider its simplest form $$ax=0.$$
F[a, x] = a*x == 0;
SolveAlways[F[a, x], x]
{{a -> 0}} 

Now let us reproduce this result going step by step by step.
! F[a, x]
(* a x != 0 *)

$\lnot (ax=0) \iff ax\neq0$ is of course equivalent to $a\neq0\land x\neq0$. This transition can be automated as follows:
CylindricalDecomposition[! F[a, x], {a, x}] // Simplify
(* a != 0 && x != 0 *)

Now Eliminate can be applied:
f[a]=Eliminate[a != 0 && x != 0, x]
(* a != 0 *)

Mathematically, the elimination of a single variable $x$ from a set of equations can be written as
$$\lnot F(\mathbf{a},x)\iff f(\mathbf{a})\land g(x)\stackrel{\text{eliminate $x$}}{\longrightarrow}f(\mathbf{a}).$$
The elimination is possible because the equations are connected with $\land$ (and) logical operation. Note, that an equation connected with $\lor$ (or) operation cannot be eliminated. Finally, the second negation, i. e. $\lnot f(\mathbf{a})$, is needed in order to return to the original problem after the elimination has been performed
! f[a]
(* a=0 *)

Subsequently, Solve is applied:
Solve(!f[a])
 {{a -> 0}} 

which is trivial here, but in general involves determining $\mathbf{a}$ from $\lnot f(\mathbf{a})$.

Thank you, I understand it better and better. Indeed SolveAlways with $x$ as the "always" variable just means eliminating $x$ from $\forall x,F(a,x)$; and the latter is equivalent to $\neg\exists x,\neg F(a,x)$; and eliminating $x$ from $\exists xG(a,x)$ is what Eliminate does.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე The first example under "Properties & Relations" in the docs for SolveAlways[] shows how the equivalence of SolveAlways and the Solve/Eliminate formulation. The parts of the code can be evaluated separately to explore, for instance, what Eliminate[! eqns, {x, y}] and ! Eliminate[! eqns, {x, y}] do. Applying Simplify to the intermediate results might be informative sometimes, too.

@MichaelE2 Thank you for pointing this out! I believe your comment makes a better answer than the one I accepted as it refers to existing documentation. Could you make it an actual answer?

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე From your comments I see that you have some fundamental misunderstanding with how and why one uses documentation. This is the first resort in case of problems, and requesting to put part of documentation is ridiculous. Voting to close your post.

@yarchik Obviously it is up to you to vote as it pleases you, but I did not propose to put part of documentation anywhere, I think it is optimal to refer to the relevant place in the documentation where one can read about it.
